# Getting and unknown error when created a pipe in angular 12/13

Tags: angular

I am currently working on project, I created a new pipe but it is showing an error. I don't know what this error means and how solve it.

```
(method) SumPipe.transform(value: any, currancy: string): any

This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'CurrencyPipe'.
```

````
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sumPipe',
})
export class SumPipe extends CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
   
  transform(value: any, currancy: string): any {
    if (value == '-') return '-';
    let symbol;
    switch (currancy) {
      case 'MYR':
        symbol = 'RM';
        break;
      case 'GBP':
        symbol = '£';
        break;
      case 'SGD':
        symbol = 'SGD';
        break;
      case 'CAD':
        symbol = 'CAD';
        break;
      case 'IDR':
        symbol = 'Rp';
        break;
      case 'EUR':
        symbol = '€';
        break;
      
      default:
        symbol = currancy;
        break;
    }
    if (value) {
      value = super.transform(value);
      value = value.replace('$', '');

      if (value < 0) {
        value = '-' + symbol + value * -1;
      } else {
        value = symbol + value;
      }

      return value;
    } else {
      return symbol + ' 0';
    }
  }
}
```


I searched for the solution but cant find
````

Comment: `override transform`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending the CurrencyPipe, which also has a transform method. Thats why typescript wants to to add the override keyword. ([read further](https://dev.to/lioness100/introducing-typescript-override-keyword-4b36))

```
export class SumPipe extends CurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
   
  override transform(value: any, currancy: string): any {
```